# The ring of real functions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have two ideals $I_1=\{ f(x)\in R | f(1)=0\}, I_2=\{ f(x)\in R| f(1)=f(2)=0\}$, where $R$ is the ring of real functions with pointwise multiplication and addition.

Are those Ideals maximal or not? if not then find an intermediate ideal: $I\ne I_i, R$ such that: $I_i\subset I\subset R$.

I think the first one is maximal and second one isn't.
For the first one suppose there exists $I\ne I_1,R$ such that $I_1\subset I\subset R$, then there exist $f(x)\in I$ such that $f(1)\ne 0$, but when adding to it $g(x)\in I_1$ we get $f(1)+g(1)\ne 0$, so $f(x)+g(x)\in I$.

Now I am not so sure, I think both aren't maximal; but then how to show this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: If $g \notin I_1$ then $I_1 + (g) = R$.

Comment: @aschepler I don't understand your hint, can you elaborate? thanks!

Comment: @aschepler how did you infer that $I_1+(g)=R$? I see now that this implies that $I_1$ is maximal.

Comment: Maximal ideals must be prime, but $I_2$ contains elements $\delta_{1x},\delta_{2x}\notin I$ (Kronecker delta) such that $\delta_{1x}\cdot\delta_{2x}=0\in I_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting ring, $R=C[0, 1]$

Define, $\phi_{a} : R\to \Bbb{R}$ by

$\phi_{a}(f) =f(a) $ .

Then, $\phi_{a} $ is a ring homomorphism.

$\ker(\phi_{a}) =\{f\in C[0,1] :\phi_{a}(f) =0\}= \{f\in C[0,1] : f(a) =0 \}$

We know that $I$ is an ideal of $R$ iff there exists a ring homomorphism from $R$ to a suitable ring (!) such that the kernel is $I$.

Now, we claim the ideal $I=\{f\in C[0,1] : f(a) =0 \}$ is maximal.

Clearly, $R/I \cong \Bbb{ R}$ [by 1st Isomorphism theorem ]

And since, $\Bbb{R}$ is a field, it follows that $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

---

$\{f:C[0, 1]: f(a) =f(b) =0\} = \{f:C[0, 1]: f(a)=0\}\cap \{f:C[0, 1]: f(b) =0\}$

(Intersection of ideals is  again an ideal)

The ideal $\{f:C[0, 1]: f(a) =f(b) =0\}$ is not maximal ideal as

$\{f:C[0, 1]: f(a) =f(b) =0\}\subset \{f:C[0, 1]: f(a) =0\}$ is an ideal of $R$ .

Comment: Did the OP say that $R$ is the ring of continuous functions on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @user26857 that's correct, I didn't say that $R$ is a ring of continuous functions on $[0,1]$. But of all real functions.

Comment: I believe I saw a similar exercise and its solution in Eidelman's Intro to Functional Analysis book years ago...

Comment: This proof does work for any ring of real-valued functions, though (or with function values in any other ring), using the core idea that $f \mapsto f(1)$ is a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Since $I_2 \subsetneq I_1 \subsetneq R$, obviously $I_2$ is not maximal.

Suppose that $I$ is an ideal properly containing $I_1$, so that $I_1 \subsetneq I \subseteq R$, and let $g$ be a real function in $I \setminus I_1$. This means $g(1) \neq 0$.

Let $f$ be any real function in $R$. We can scale $g$ to match the value of $f$ at $x=1$:

$$ h(x) = \frac{f(1)}{g(1)} g(x) $$

Since $g \in I$ and $\frac{f(1)}{g(1)}$ is just a constant real number, $h \in I$. Then we can write $f$ as

$$ f = (f-h) + h $$

Since $h(1) = f(1)$, $(f-h)(1) = 0$, and so $f-h \in I_1 \subset I$. Since both $f-h$ and $h$ are in $I$, their sum $f$ is in also $I$. This has shown that every real function $f$ is in $I$, so $I=R$. In other words, $I_1 \subsetneq I \subsetneq R$ is impossible; $I_1$ is maximal.